# Помогите с авторизацией Google Oauth2

Tags: java, android, авторизация, oauth2

Есть метод авторизации через VK API, после него запускается RecyclerView!!
Сейчас хочу сделать авторизацию через GOOGLE Oauth2, что бы когда токен одобрен, то сразу же запускалась RecyclerView, но не понимаю как!!!!

Использую для авторизации GOOGLE Oauth2 стороннюю библиотеку [тык](https://github.com/sviter-pro/SocialAuthHelper)

```
public void onClickLoginVK(View view) {
        VKSdk.login(this, scopes);
    }

public void onClickLoginGL(View view) {
        googlePlusClient.getProfile(new GooglePlusClient.GooglePlusResultCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onProfileLoaded(GooglePlusProfile googlePlusProfile) {
            }
        });
    }
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        googlePlusClient.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
                // Пользователь успешно авторизовался
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Авторизация прошла успешно!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                // Произошла ошибка авторизации (например, пользователь запретил авторизацию)
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ошибка авторизации....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        })) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

Что надо написать в `onActivityResult`, чтобы после получения токена открывалась

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: А что в доке на этот счёт сказано?

Comment: ничего....есть вообще подобная реализация?

Comment: Так это же типа ваша библиотека (форк), вот вы сам себе и расскажите как ее юзать. Кто тут будет за вас код лопатить?